# How to extract value from hash in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-2.2

I have a Hash and need to use the value year from a variable in it
The example is:

```
2.2.4 :001 > @values_project
=> [#<CustomValue id: 20367, customized_type: "Project", customized_id: 492, custom_field_id: 64, year: "2017">]
```

and I need the year
so when I try `@value_hash.year` receive the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for
#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000712fb18>
```

I don't understand why

Comment: @values_project[:year]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@value_hash` is not a `hash`, it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (as the error states).

In your example, `@value_hash` has only one member. To get that member, which is an instance of the class `CustomValue` (which is still not a `hash`!), you can do:

```
custom_value = @value_hash.first
```

Then, to get the year, you can do:

```
custom_value.year
```

Or, you could do it in one shot as:

```
@value_hash.first.year
```

Which is just a long way of saying exactly what Sachin R said (so you should accept their answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get the value for the key year and your hash is @values_project then you would use
    `@values_project[:year]`

Answer (score 2):

since it is array of objects use like that

```
@values_project.each do |value_project|
  value_project.year
end
```

or

```
@values_project.first.year
```

Comment: It's not *exactly* an 'array of objects'. It's an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But, hey, I know what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways as well :

```
@value_project[0].year
```